# Firefox 6 - disable self-signed certificate alert

Tags: ssl, firefox

I'm using few webapps that are using self signed SSL certificates. I remember from old FF, that when there was something wrong with certificate, page was displayed informing about how unsafe this is but it allowed to add an exception. But in firefox 6 I'm getting and alert window, where I can only click OK. I have to add exceptions by hand, which is very inconvenient. Is there any way to disable this alert and bring this warning page?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is to get an SSL certificate from a CA on browser's trusted list, instead of using self-signed certificates.

You can get free Class 1 SSL certificates from [**StartSSL**](http://www.startssl.com/).  It only takes a few minutes to receive them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the certificate check entirely.

If the webapps are reachable from the Internet, you can try [Perspectives](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/perspectives/) or [Convergence](http://convergence.io/), which use different methods for verifying SSL certificates and can automatically add exceptions if the certificate seems to be valid.